# PHP gd create image, add to folder and db

Tags: php, gd

I have created this image:

```
    header('content-type: image/jpeg');

//Load our base image 
    $image = imagecreatefrompng(BASEPATH . '../images/blogMainImage.png');

//Setup colors and font file 
    $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $font_path = BASEPATH . '../fonts/ACME Explosive.ttf';

//Get the positions of the text string
    $text = wordwrap($_POST['title'], 15, "\n");



//Create Month
    imagettftext($image, 16, 0, 20, 40, $black, $font_path, $text);

//Create final image 
    imagejpeg($image, '', 100);

//Clear up memory;
    imagedestroy($image);
```

I have successfully created the image. Now what i need to do is to get the created image filename, save the filename to db and file to a upload folder..

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: i think there must be a header function to do this.. I searched online.. but got nothing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you need:

```
$name ='myimage.png';
// make sure you create a folder called **images** in the directory where the script is and give it write permissions.
$save_path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/images/'.$name); 
// I assume that you want to use the image in a website.
$imageurl = "http://www.mysite.com/images/$name"; 
imagejpeg($im, $save_path); // saves the image to **this_dir/images/myimage.png**
imagedestroy($im);
```

in regards to store the filename in a db, you'll need to set the the database first and then use something like this:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Photos(save_path, imageurl)
VALUES ("$save_path", "$imageurl")");

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: So what do you need ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also add this codes:

```
$actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
$tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
{
           mysql_query("UPDATE lms_users SET userPic='$actual_image_name' WHERE userId='$_SESSION[email]'");                        
}
    else
    echo "failed";
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a name and a route to save the image:

```
// Save the image as 'test.jpg'
$name_image="test.jpg";
imagejpeg($im, 'folder_to_save_image/'.$name_image);
```

and you can save the name in your data base

check [imagejpeg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)